# Most efficient way to implement RLS and CLS on SQL Server, considering that the users and usergroups metadata is stored in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, row-level-security

I'm looking for a very efficient way to control row level access and column level access, considering that users and user groups metadata is stored in the database. Our application is using Entity Framework and we have to ensure that all code access to some record and it's columns is filtered based on the user access to the requested data.

Comment: There is a built-in RLS implementation starting with SQL Server 2016. Simplistic and amateurish, sure, but it might be enough for your purposes.

Comment: I've found this article about the "Label Security Toolkit", I'll give it a try

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3030/implementing-sql-server-row-and-cell-level-security/

Comment: Another good article on this in: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/01/21/limiting-access-to-data-using-row-level-security/ ; This one responds to a requirement I have in the FAQs section: "What if my application uses connection pooling with a single login for all users?"